# How to get file upload without a form

Tags: forms, symfony, upload

my controller receives post data. It's not from a Symfony generated form, but from an AngularJS custom form using `FormData`.

The normal parameters are received normally in the request parameter bag, but how do I get the file that is uploaded? Do I need to manually do the same that the form's `handleRequest` does?

My document is the same as the [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).

So I need to get an UploadFile from the post request to call this method on the document entity:

`public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)`

How do I receive a upload manually in Symfony 2 (without using the form builder in any way)?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The [Request](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) has a FileBag, similar to the ParameterBag

So I could get the file specified easily with:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
$file = $this->getRequest()->files->get('file');
```

and use the document as is from the cookbook:

```
$document = new Document();
$document->setFile($file);
$lead->setDocument($document);
```

Comment: How can I set the content of file bag? I am using `https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz/blob/master/lib/Buzz/Browser.php` and I have to send a POST request with file bag set. I have fileObj in my code. I verfied it with `is_file()` method.

Comment: can you answer my question as well? I am facing the same problem here is my question.      https://stackoverflow.com/q/44352796/1395965

Comment: `$this->getRequest()` seems to be deprecated as of 2.4 and removed in 3.0. `$request->files->get('filename')` worked for me

Comment: Also check that PHP is accepting files. Here there are some `php.ini` directives https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads like for example the `file_uploads` that must be set to on, or the `upload_max_filesize` among others.