# Can the Form data in Symfony

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I'm trying to do a file upload in Symfony. It starts from the client side using `Javascript`. I've created a `FormData` object in which I append the content of the multiple file input. This containt that I want to get after in Symfony side .

I've created a Symfony `FileType` that represent a file.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('attachment',FileType::class,array(
            'label'    => 'Files upload',
            'multiple' => true,
            'attr'     => array(
                'style' => "visibility: hidden;"
            )

        ))
        ->add('button',ButtonType::class,array(
            'label' => 'Add files',
            'attr'     => array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            )

        ))
    ;
}
```

I'm using Ajax to send my Form

```
$('#corebundle_files_attachment').change(function () {
    let formData = new FormData();
    $(this.files).each(function () {
        formData.append('attachment[]', this);
    });

let url = '/files/upload';
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });

});
```

Here is the attachment variable representation in the entity:

```
 /** @var $attachment
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @Assert\File()
 */
private $attachment;
```

I did a simple method to dispaly the form contents in my controller. I thought that the `handleRequest` method will automatically handle the filling of form. In a second time, I try to display the contents of the form but it is always empty. I have doubts that I did some things wrong in the javascript side.

```
/**
 * @Route("/files/upload", name="files_upload")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function uploadFileTestAction(Request $request){

    $form = $this->createForm(FilesType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $files = $form->getData();

    dump($files);
    exit;
}
```

**UPDATE** :

I managed to display the loaded files. But not via the form

[image]

**The request headers :**

[image]

**UPDATE** :

Resolved from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400216/how-to-get-file-upload-without-a-form)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I can not get my uploaded files in the server side. the `$form->getData() `is null.

Comment: Check if your upload request has the correct headers set. (Browser dev tools, network panel.)

Comment: I've updated the question with headers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400216/how-to-get-file-upload-without-a-form similar question

Comment: @tonoslfx That's it. Thanks