# problem sending user input file vue js to symfony php

Tags: php, vue.js, symfony

`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ2In.png)i have a problem sending a picture file from the frontend(vue js) to backend(php symfony). I have made a form where the user can input an image file, now i want to send the image file to the backend and save it there. the file is send with a fetch multipart form, problem is php doesnt read it as file but as string. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kMZ9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OplBv.png)

```
---vue.js---
catchImg(event) {
      this.imgFile = event.target.files[0]
      this.form.naamImg = event.target.files[0].name
      //console.log(this.form.imgFile)
      //console.log(this.form.naamImg);

      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append("file", this.imgFile)

      fetch('https://localhost:8000/savePicture', {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData,
        method: "POST"
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
    },
---symfony---
/**
     * @Route("/savePicture", name="savePicture")
     */
    public function savePicture(Request $request){
        $data = $request->getContent();
        dd($data);
        //dd($_FILES);
        //$destination = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir').'/public/uploads';
        //$data->move($destination);
        $response = new JsonResponse(
            [
                'picture saved' => 'ok',
            ],
            JsonResponse::HTTP_CREATED
        );
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Files can be accessed via `$request->files->get()` method, as the `Request` has `FileBag`, similar to `ParameterBag` - [more in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400216/how-to-get-file-upload-without-a-form)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that wasn't it, in the mean time i found the problem myself. I was getting the file using event, and for some reason this made the file in to a blobfile. If i get the file using queryselector, it does get the file correctly without changing it.